# Why is "Assertion failed: You can only add a 'story' record to this relationship" is being thrown?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I don't think I understand how to set a belongsTo relationship.  I'm using 
ember-1.1.2, and ember data beta3.  Any help appreciated.

The relationship definitions:

```
App.Story = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    setting: DS.attr('string'),
    status: DS.attr('string'),
    chapters: DS.hasMany('chapter',{async: true}),
    cast: DS.hasMany('actor', {async: true})
 });

App.Chapter = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    number: DS.attr('number'),
    description: DS.attr('string'),
    story: DS.belongsTo('story'),
    scenes: DS.hasMany('scene',{async: true})
});
```

The routes:

```
this.resource('story', {path: '/story'}, function() {
            this.route('edit', {path: '/:story_id'})
            this.route('new')
            this.resource('chapter', {path:"/:story_id/chapter"},   function() {
                    this.route('edit', {path: '/:chapter_id/edit'})
                    this.route('new')
                    this.resource('scene', {path:":chapter_id/scene"}, function() {
                            this.route('edit', {path: '/:scene_id/edit'})
                            this.route('new')
                    })
            })
    })
```

Where the error occurs:

```
App.ChapterNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    setupController: function( controller, model) {
            this.controllerFor('chapter.edit').setProperties({isNew:true, content:model})
    },

    model: function(params) {
            var chapter = this.store.createRecord('chapter')
            this.store.find('story', params.story_id).then(function( story) {
                    chapter.set('story', story)  //ERROR HAPPENS HERE
                    story.get('chapters').push(chapter)
            })

            return chapter
    },

    renderTemplate: function() {
            this.render('chapter.edit')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

story_id doesn't exist in that route's model hook, it only lives on the ChapterRoute (aka story_id is undefined and you are probably not getting a story).  You can use modelFor to get the model from the chapter's route and get the from that model if it exists.

Here's a jsbin showing it working

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/1/edit